# Stream radio is not working with Media Player in Android

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm working in an android application. I have a problem trying to playback a radio stream. The url is:

```
http://2583.live.streamtheworld.com/XHMFMAAC?type=.flv
```

I also try with:

```
http://2583.live.streamtheworld.com/XHMFMAAC
```

And with:

```
http://2583.live.streamtheworld.com/XHMFMAAC?type=.mp3
```

Also I tried to find the url with the `.mp3` format but I didn't find it. Any idea how I can this to work?

**Edit**

I'm going to try with this library. https://code.google.com/p/android-openmxplayer/ . I have tested the above urls and it works great.

Comment: Your url is not right.any error found?

Comment: Yes. `Media unknown` error. I know there are not right. But I'm trying to get this work with those urls. Is that possible?

Comment: If you working with radio, then there is some .pls file in which streaming url is given.So you can work with .pls file for fm radio streaming.

Comment: The `.pls` format didn't. What I did was extracting the url from the pls file using `vlc`. The url is above. But they are not working.

Comment: In vlc player when  you open pls file it is playing radio or not?

Comment: Yes, they play normally in vlc. But not in my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73473/discussion-between-gabriel-munumel-and-arun-kumar).